# Filter search with Javascript, character with accent equal to coomon

Tags: javascript, search, filtering, special-characters, diacritics

I´m doing something just like this [example](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FOXZUO2S2L1C)


Is there a way to equal on the search the characters with or without accents? example áéíóú equal to aeiou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accented characters have completely different ASCII values than their unaccented counterpart. You would have to create a custom function for all input you'd want to accept as valid for each English letter.

From referencing [this](https://www.asciitable.com/) ASCII table

```
e => è
101 => 138
```

Write your function expression for mapping values like that.